# Integration of $e^{|x|} $ in computation of expectation

Tags: probability, integration, random-variables, expectation, riemann-integration

I have a sequence of iid random variables $(X_n,n\in\mathbb{N})$ with density $f(x)= \frac{1}{2} e^{-|x|}$.

I need to verify that $M_n = \exp(\theta\sum_{i=1}^n X_i - nA(\theta))$ is integrable, for some values of $\theta$. Now, I should have that: $$ E(|M_n|) = \prod_{i=1}^nE( |\exp(\theta X_i - n A(\theta))|) =\prod_{i=1}^nE( \exp(\theta X_i - n A(\theta))) $$
while computing the integral, I splitted it to get rid of the absolute value:
$$ \prod_{i=1}^n 1/2\bigg(\int_{-\infty}^0 \exp(x)\exp(\theta x-nA(\theta))dx +\int_{0}^{+\infty} \exp(-x)\exp(\theta x-nA(\theta))dx\bigg) $$

But then in the solution I found :
$$ \prod_{i=1}^n 1/2\bigg(\int_{0}^{\infty} \exp(x(\theta-1)-A(\theta))dx +\int_{0}^{\infty} \exp(-x(\theta+1)-A(\theta))dx\bigg) $$

I understand that $M_n\geq 0$ so that might be a reason to do this, but then I don't see how the two expressions might be equivalent, did I do something wrong? Can you explain to me what is the rationale behind the second expression?

Answer (score 1):

Note that the last integral in your expression is equal to their first integral.

Moreover, if you substitute $x=-y$ in you second integral you will get their first integral. Note that when changing the boundaries of integration gives a minus sign as well as $dy = -d x$ which thus cancel each other out.

I hope this helps. If you have any comments or want to see the details, feel free to comment!

**Edit** The rationale behind this substitution is no more than just wanting something positive to integrate over/it looks better.